# WPF Form Debugging Stucking

Tags: wpf, debugging

I'm sorry for bad English because I'm not native.

First of all, A predefined WPF form codes here, Whenever i press F11 and the codes are debugged from beginning, , the debugging process stucks at bw_ProgressChanged Event. The debugging process skip DoWork method Easily. Why?
By the way, the codes are ran fine.

```
         using System;
enter code hereusing System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        #region bw
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bool flg = true;
        int tempSec = 0;
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (flg)
            {
                if (tempSec < DateTime.Now.Second)
                {
                    tempSec = DateTime.Now.Second;

                    bw.ReportProgress(tempSec);
                }
            }

          }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtSecondCounter.Text = "Done";
      /*      if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)//Check if the worker has been cancelled or if an error occured
            {
                string result = (string)e.Result;//Get the result from the background thread
                lblAlarm.Text = result;//Display the result to the user
                lblCounter.Content = "Done";
                lblCounterTimes.Content = (++countTimes).ToString();
                m_Timer.Dispose();
                if ((bool)chkLoop.IsChecked)
                    btnStart_Click(btnStart, null);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                lblAlarm.Text = "User Cancelled";
            }
            else
            {
                lblCounter.Content = "An error has occured";
            }
            btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
            */

        }
        private void bw_ProgressChanged( object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            txtSecondCounter.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
         }


        #endregion

        private void btnPlayPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            flg = !flg;
            if (flg)
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            if (btnPlayPause.Content.ToString() == "Pause")
                btnPlayPause.Content = "Play";
            else
                btnPlayPause.Content = "Pause";

        }
    }
}
 }
```

The Xaml code:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    >
<DockPanel Name="pnlMain" LastChildFill="False">

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="40" Background="AliceBlue" LastChildFill="False">


    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="40" Background="AliceBlue" LastChildFill="False">

        <TextBlock Name="txtSecondCounter" Width="100" Height="30" Background="Yellow">0</TextBlock>
        <Button Width="100" Name="btnPlayPause" Click="btnPlayPause_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Left">Pause</Button>
        <TextBox Width="100"></TextBox>
    </DockPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

It look like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what problem you are having based on your description but you do realize that this part of the DoWork code will only be true until tempsec reaches 59...

```
if (tempSec < DateTime.Now.Second)
{
    tempSec = DateTime.Now.Second;
...
```